# Why am I not getting the result of sorted function in expected order?

Tags: python, sorting

```
print activities
activities  = sorted(activities,key = lambda item:item[1])
print activities
```

Activities in this case is a list of tuples like `(start_number,finish_number)` the output of the above code according to me should be the list of values sorted according the the increasing order of `finish_number`. When I tried the above code in shell I got the following output. I am not sure why the second list is not sorted according the the increasing order of the `finish_number`. Please help me in understanding this.

```
[('1', '4'), ('3', '5'), ('0', '6'), ('5', '7'), ('3', '9'), ('5', '9'), ('6', '10'), ('8', '11'), ('8', '12'), ('2', '14'), ('12', '16')]
[('6', '10'), ('8', '11'), ('8', '12'), ('2', '14'), ('12', '16'), ('1', '4'), ('3', '5'), ('0', '6'), ('5', '7'), ('3', '9'), ('5', '9')]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are sorting strings instead of integers: in that case, `10` is "smaller" than `4`. To sort on integers, convert it to this:

```
activites = sorted(activities,key = lambda item:int(item[1]))
print activities
```

Results in:

```
[('1', '4'), ('3', '5'), ('0', '6'), ('5', '7'), ('3', '9'), ('5', '9'), ('6', '10'), ('8', '11'), ('8', '12'), ('2', '14'), ('12', '16')]
```

Comment: ohh Great i never noticed that it was string , thanks for the reply

Answer (score 6):

Your items are being compared as strings, not as numbers. Thus, since the `1` character comes before `4` lexicographically, it makes sense that `10` comes before `4`.

You need to cast the value to an int first:

```
activities  = sorted(activities,key = lambda item:int(item[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are sorting strings, not numbers. Strings get sorted character by character.

So, for example `'40'` is greater than `'100'` because character `4` is larger than `1`.

You can fix this on the fly by simply casting the item as an integer.

```
 activities  = sorted(activities,key = lambda item: int(item[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're not storing the number as a number, but as a string. The string `'10'` comes before the string `'2'`. Try:

```
activities = sorted(activities, key=lambda i: int(i[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Look for a BROADER solution to your problem**: Convert your data from `str` to `int` immediately on input, work with it as `int` (otherwise you'll be continually be bumping into little problems like this), and format your data as `str` for output.

This principle applies generally, e.g. when working with non-ASCII string data, do UTF-8 -> unicode -> UTF-8; don't try to manipulate undecoded text.